# Serialization error when getting error response

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm getting an error and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```html
"Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'MessageHistoryResponse', got string starting with: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name=" ...
```

The client code is simpy:

```cs
var client = new JsonServiceClient(Url);

try
{
    var messageHistoryResponse = client.Send(new MessageHistory {
        Take = 20,
        Skip = 0
    });
}
catch (WebServiceException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

I have a request filter in place as follows:

```cs
public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    var token = req.Headers["authtoken"];

    if (token != null)
    {
        //Authenticated code
    }

    if (_logger.IsDebugEnabled)
        _logger.DebugFormat("[Token {0}] Access Denied", token);

    res.ReturnAuthRequired();
}
```

This is following one of the examples but instead of receiving a `WebException`,it throws a Serialization exception. I'm not sure how best to handle this?

All of my services use a standard requestDto/responseDto pattern. From the docs I was expecting a `WebException` to be thrown, which I could then handle. But instead it's a `SerializationException` and doesn't report that the Auth failed.

Anyone got any ideas to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter hasn't set the content type to be `application/json` so the unauthorised error is being output as html which the `JsonServiceClient` doesn't expect.

You can set the response type and then `throw` the error

```cs
public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    ...
    res.ContentType = "application/json";
    throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "401", "Invalid token, access denied");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I configure the service, I use the following code: 

JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;

SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api", DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json });

Does this not default the return format to JSON?

Comment: @Dion You're welcome, I hope it helps. The `MimeTypes.Json` will only apply for the return type of the Service action methods, it does not apply to filters, as filters are designed to handle the raw request.

Comment: @Dion did the suggestion resolve your issue? Or are you still seeing an error?

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and unfortunately it hasn't made any difference. The same error is returned.

Comment: @Dion What's the response when you make the request through a web browser? i.e. doing something like `http://<server>:<port>/<MessageHistoryAction>/?Take=20&Skip=0&x-http-method-override=POST`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the answer with help from the forums. The problem I was experiencing was due to a conflict between the ASP .NET membership provider and ServiceStack. When a 401 Unauthorised response was received, ASP .NET hijacks the request and takes over.

I changed my code to instead return a 403 Forbidden and I was back in business.

So frustrating but I'm glad we were able to get to the bottom of it in the end.

Thanks for your help.